# WebGL: get error/warning message text as a string

Tags: javascript, runtime-error, webgl

When an error occurs within WebGL, a warning message is usually displayed in the browser's console.

For example, trying to create a texture which is too big:

```js
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D,     // target
    0,                 // level
    gl.RGBA,           // internalformat
    1000000,           // width
    1000000,           // height
    0,                 // border
    gl.RGBA,           // format
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // type
    null               // data
);
```

Chrome and Safari display this warning message in the console:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range
```

Firefox displays this warning message:

```
Error: WebGL: texImage2D: the maximum width for level 0 is 4096
```

How can I programmatically obtain this message from WebGL?

I'm looking for something like `gl.getErrorMessage()` which would return a string.

#### What I've tried

WebGL errors don't throw JavaScript errors, so it's not possible to `catch` them to get their `message` property.

[`gl.getError()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml) only returns an `ErrorCode` enum value, such as `INVALID_VALUE`.

[`gl.getShaderInfoLog()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderInfoLog.xml) only provides error messages relating to a specific shader (eg. compilation errors).

[`gl.getProgramInfoLog()`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgramInfoLog.xml) only provides error messages relating to a specific program (eg. linking errors).

Khronos have created a [debugging wrapper](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Debugging#Programmatically_Debugging_WebGL_applications) called `WebGLDebugUtils`, but it seems the only method relating to error messages is `glEnumToString()`, which converts an enum value (eg. `INVALID_VALUE`) to a string.

Comment: You may have a look at https://github.com/greggman/webgl-lint third party library that wraps WebGL context and add extra debugging features. This library also feats a custom extension that allows tagging objects for extra contextual metadata on errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, You can't.

WebGL only returns error numbers through `gl.getError()`. The rest of it is just stuff the browsers added to help devs find their errors since they already have to do lots of validation for WebGL.

Maybe you should [propose a WebGL extension for it](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/public-mailing-list/).

Comment: Many thanks. I've noticed that for certain errors (eg. trying to render an NPOT texture which doesn't meet the [requirements](https://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/FAQ#Why_don.27t_my_textures_render.3F)), a warning message is logged in the console (which can't be obtained programmatically) and `gl.getError()` returns `NO_ERROR`. I guess this is what you mean by devs "having to do lots of validation"? Since WebGL can silently fail to render an NPOT texture, then it's the responsibility of the developer to verify that the NPOT texture meets the requirements before attempting to render it?

Comment: Yes, the spec OpenGL ES spec says that's not technically an error but it's a hard issue to find. The WebGL implementations have to check anyway so they don't let a newer version of GL allow something that an ES 2.0 doesn't allow (otherwise things wouldn't work across browsers), so.. since they're already checking they can print a warning for you.